# How to assign jQuery variable value to php variable

Tags: javascript, php, json, wsdl, soap-client

I'm using `jQuery` to generate table based on `JSON` output.In this code `JSON` value taking from a `SoapClient` . This working fine and here is my output

[image]

Now i need to assign the ID column value to `PHP` variable and pass that `PHP` value to `PHP` funtion. I know `Javascript` works on the client side and `PHP` works on the server side. So then have any solution to do this. I used this code snippet to get 1st column value

`<button onclick="myFunction(this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[0].textContent)" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Get Value</button>`

how can i assign this to PHP variable.

Here is my code

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost:2327/ManageSemesterService.svc?wsdl');

$respoMS = $client->SelectBatchTimetableJSONPara(array('para' => "Batch 8"));
$valMS = $respoMS->SelectBatchTimetableJSONParaResult;

?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').append('<div class="container" ></div><br>');

    var html = '<div class="container" ><table class="table table-striped"></div>';
    html += '<tr>';
    var flag = 0;

    var data2   =   <?php echo $valMS; ?>;
    $.each(data2[0], function(index, value){
        html += '<th>'+index+'</th>';
    });
    html += '</tr>';

     $.each(data2, function(index, value){

        html += '<tr>';

        $.each(value, function(index2, value2){

            if(value2 == "Java"){
                html += '<td style="background-color: #7e57c2;">'+value2+'</td>';
            }
            else{
                html += '<td>'+value2+'</td>';
            }

        });

        html += '<td><button onclick="myFunction(this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[0].textContent)" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Get Value</button></td>';


        html += '</tr>';

     });

     html += '</table>';
     $('body').append(html);
     console.log(html);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why do u need to pass it back to `php`? Why don't you just move the logic from `php` to `javascript`? What are you trying to do with the `ID`?

Comment: @brso05 Suppose this is a timetable. if i need to cancel the lecture of Java, i need to pass the above id to my c# application through SoapClient. so then i faced this problem

Comment: you can use `ajax` then to call your `php` code...

Comment: @brso05 i don't know how to this with ajax, coz i never work with ajax. can u help me to solve this.please

Comment: This is a lot more in depth...I suggest you read some tutorials on `php` web services and `ajax/javascript` how to call them...

Comment: @brso05 ok. thank u

Comment: No problem!....

Answer (score 0):

There are no possibilities of assigning a client data to server script data. You can always send data to server through Ajax and then you can process the data.

Comment: place a click event for all rows and assign the id of the row in data-id attribute. On click of the row get the data-id and send the data to the server. In server get the data in controller and process the data and send back the result to client. This all can happen without any disturbance to UI. After getting the data in client display or process the data in client.

Answer (score 0):

So you are needing to get the ID from a HTML Tag and pass it to PHP for Server Side processing?

Ajax is your friend! http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  data: {this can be json}
  context: document.body
}).success(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
```

That is a really rough example on how to do it, look at the Tech Docs for more info.

Essentially you will put your info to pass into PHP in the data section and in the url is the link to the page that parses the data into php.

The sucess function is activated if the url and data are successfully passed into php. You will need to put some error handler in your php to return if the data is not dealt with correctly.

Comment: Thank u. I will try